# Condition<Expected>.Equals': Interfaces cannot declare types

Tags: c#

I am getting this error:

> "*Condition.Equals': Interfaces cannot declare types*".

How do I do this correctly?

```
 public interface Condition<Expected> {

        public bool verify(Expected expected, object actual);

        public class Equals : Condition<object> {   

            public bool verify(object expected, object actual) {
                return expected==actual || (expected!=null && expected.Equals(actual));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Interfaces can't contain class definitions. maybe you want ot create abstract class instead?

Answer (score 0):

Move class declaration *outside* the interface; all you can do within the interface is declaring *methods* and *properties*:

```
public interface Condition<Expected> {
  // you can't declare interface method as public or, say, private: 
  // it's the implementing class that provides the access modifier
  bool verify(Expected expected, object actual);
}

public class Equals : Condition<object> {   
  public bool verify(object expected, object actual) {
    return expected == actual || (expected != null && expected.Equals(actual));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to C#, just translated this from my Java code so I'm still getting the hang of it. Thanks!